# Regex to reduce comma separated category ids to top level id

Tags: regex, netsuite

Very new to regex so question one would be is this possible?

I have products that can be in multiple categories/ subcategories, but for reporting, I just want to attribute them once per top category.

**Original data:**
1010,1012,1012610,1014243,10147048956,2010,201150205,2011506,2015470

**Desired Result:**
1010,1012,1014,2010,2011,2015

*Details*
1010 is unchanged
1012,1012610 reduce to 1 instance of 1012
1014243,10147048956 reduce to 1 instance of 1014
2010 is unchanged
201150205,2011506 reduce to 1 instance of 2011
2015470 is reduced to 2015

My current pattern (?|(10..)|(20..)) works well with exception to the following bold sections:
1010,1012,10126**10,1**014243,10147048956,2010,201150**205,**2011506,2015470

As for reducing, I am at a loss for where to start.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or direction.

Comment: Which language/regex engine?

Comment: I am using the regex in NetSuite which is using a flavor of SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\b(\w{4})
1010,1012,1012610,1014243,10147048956,2010,201150205,2011506,2015470

after applying regex "\b(\w{4})" can you collect values in Set it will make those element unique.

Comment: Thank you! I had just come up with a much clunkier way to get my number pattern, but this is much better and makes perfect sense. I appreciate the direction!